# Is needing to refresh the Project Explorer Pane in Eclipse when the file structure changes a bug or a feature?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I'm kinda torn on this one...

It could be a feature, because then if the file structure of your project changes on disk, then you'll be able to refer back to project explorer to see what you had before the change, before you refresh.

On the other hand it's a little annoying, but not too bad when you get used to it...

So which is it?  A bug or a feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can chose which behavior you want:

Under *Window* -> *preferences* -> *general* -> *workspace*, there is an option "[X] Refresh automatically"

So, the answer to you question: It's not a bug :)

Comment: Nice! I've been using Eclipse for years and I had no idea you could do that!  

That's another thing I like about Eclipse, the more you use it, it seems the more stuff there is to know about Eclipse; incredible.

Well now we know what the default behavior is, and that it isn't a bug. :)